# Cannot import module in nodejs with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am using ExpressJS with Typescript.

I was import a module and I get undefined when I tried to console.log it. Some modules can import and work fine. But some modules get undefined.

I don't understand why and how. Anyone has experience on that issue. Please help me.

Thank you so much!!

**Structure of folder:**

```
- dist/
- src/
  - api
  - database
  - middleware
  - routers
  - server.ts
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.json"]
}
```

**server.ts** The middleware work fine.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import http from 'http';

import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';

import middleware from './middleware';
import database from './database/models';

const app: Application = express();

app.use(middleware.appMiddleware); // The middleware work fine.

app.get('/', (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Welcome to Meet You website!');
});

const server = new http.Server(app);
const PORT = 3000;

database.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  middleware.redis.start((error) => {
    if (!error) {
      server.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`The server listen on port ${PORT}`);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**But in api/routers.ts** My middleware is undefined.

```
import { Router } from 'express';

import middleware from '../../middleware';

import signInController from './sign-in/controllers';
import signUpController from './sign-up/controllers';
import changePasswordController from './change-password/controllers';

const authRouters: Router = Router();

console.log('middleware', middleware); // undefined

authRouters.route('/sign-in').post(signInController);
authRouters.route('/sign-up').post(signUpController);
authRouters
  .route('/change-password')
  .put(middleware.jwt.verifyToken, changePasswordController);

export default authRouters;
```

**middleware/index.ts**

```
import appMiddleware from './app';
import jwt from './jwt';
import redis from './redis';

export default {
  appMiddleware,
  jwt,
  redis,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run below command in terminal :

```
npm install @types/node
```